# Shadow set on uibezierpath in draw(rect:) removed when view is redrawn

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, core-graphics

**Problem:**

I've implemented a collapsible header view with a curved bottom border and a gradient layer that sits above my scrollView. The header has a drop shadow that is drawn in its draw(rect:) function. The shadow gives the bottom border a glow effect. Everything looks good, but when setNeedsDisplay() is called on my header or the view is redrawn, the drop shadow goes away.

**Question:**

How do I make the drop shadow persist when the view is redrawn?

**Code:**

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)

    let p1 = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.height * 0.8)
    let p2 = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height * 1.06)
    let p3 = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: self.frame.height * 0.8)
    let p4 = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: 0)
    let p5 = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

    let path = UIBezierPath()

    path.move(to: p1)
    path.addQuadCurve(to: p3, controlPoint: p2)
    path.addLine(to: p4)
    path.addLine(to: p5)
    path.addLine(to: p1)
    path.close()

    self.shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    self.layer.mask = self.shapeLayer

    if !self.didSetGradient {

        self.gradient = CustomColors.blueGreenBackgroundGradient(frame: path.bounds)

        self.gradient.mask = shapeLayer
        self.gradient.masksToBounds = true
        self.gradient.removeFromSuperlayer()

        self.layer.insertSublayer(self.gradient, at: 0)

        self.didSetGradient = true
    }

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    context?.saveGState()
    context?.setShadow(offset: CGSize(width: 0, height: 2.5), blur: 15, color: CustomColors.green.cgColor)
    CustomColors.blueGreen.setStroke()
    UIColor.clear.setFill()
    path.lineWidth = 5
    path.stroke()
    context?.restoreGState()        
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you need `setNeedsDisplay` like the answer given, instead - have you set a breakpoint in `draw(rect;)`? Here's what I'm concerned with: your gradient is inside an `if !self.didSetGradient` and how will a *second* call to things execute this? Is there someplace you are *resetting* `didSetGradient`?

Comment: @dfd I don't need `setNeedsDisplay` but the `draw(rect:)` function is called whenever the view needs to be updated and that's when I come across the issue. I call `setNeedsDisplay` to force the view to be redrawn to help with debugging. `self.didSetGradient` is a class var that is declared false when the view is instantiated, so the gradient only gets set once. Without that conditional, the gradient was not masking properly when it was set a second time when the view was redrawn. Advice for both this and the drop shadow would be much appreciated!

Comment: An answer, now deleted, suggested calling `setNeedsDisplay`. I was referencing that. I agree that `draw(rect:) is the correct place for the code. BUT... once you set `didSetGradient` to true - meaning the *first* time things are drawn - how does it get set back to false? Unless you set it to false *and then* redraw, the gradient won't be redrawn.

Comment: @dfd ahh I see. I do not set `didSetGradient` back to `false`. In testing, the gradient always remains even after the view is redrawn. Would this have anything to do with the drop shadow disappearing?

Comment: Probably not. I don't really know why it disappears. From here, your code looks good to me. The only thing I saw was with `didSetGradient`. Wish I could be of more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aight was able to figure this one out. The bezier path shadow was getting hidden when the view was redrawn because the layer mask was getting set to the shapeLayer. My solution was to draw the curved shadow using the layer's `shadowPath` property and inserting the `shapeLayer` as a subLayer instead of masking the layer. Make sure to add the `shapeLayer` before you add the gradient, so the gradient appears on top of the `shapeLayer`. The `didSetGradient` block is pretty tacky as @dfd mentioned, but it's working for now!

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)

    let p1 = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.height * 0.8)
    let p2 = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height * 1.06)
    let p3 = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: self.frame.height * 0.8)
    let p4 = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: 0)
    let p5 = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

    let path = UIBezierPath()

    path.move(to: p1)
    path.addQuadCurve(to: p3, controlPoint: p2)
    path.addLine(to: p4)
    path.addLine(to: p5)
    path.addLine(to: p1)
    path.close()

    self.shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath

    if !self.didSetGradient {
            self.layer.insertSublayer(shapeLayer, at: 0)

        self.gradient = CustomColors.blueGreenBackgroundGradient(frame: path.bounds)
        self.gradient.mask = shapeLayer
        self.gradient.masksToBounds = true
        self.layer.insertSublayer(self.gradient, at: 0)

        self.didSetGradient = true
    }       

    self.layer.shadowPath = startPath.cgPath
    self.layer.shadowColor = CustomColors.blueGreen.cgColor
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 8
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 7)
    self.layer.masksToBounds = false
    self.clipsToBounds = false
}
```